# Checkbox with both a default content values as well as one from binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a a checkbox in XAML where i need the content to have a default value, lets say: "FooText", but also a binding to a field in an object, that can change.
 The idea is that is that at load the checkbox should show the default content, but when an object is loaded the content should change accordingly.

Is this possible, and if so, how? I have some idea that i might be doable in a template, but since im pretty new to WPF i have no idea how to achieve the required result.

Im using the MVVM pattern.

Hope that someone might have a good idea:-D

Answer (score 3):

You could use a default object for that, where you set all properties to the default value you want and then use it as DataContext.

Another thing is the [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) on Bindings. Using that you can set a default value to show if the target value of a binding is null.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "default value". WPF Databinding allows for a few ways to handle "default values":

- [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx): This allows you to specify a value if there is an issue with the databinding itself. For example, if you are binding to a property that does not exist on the viewmodel (DataContext).
- [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx): This allows you to specify a value if the binding value is null, which is very possible for string values.

You can use both if you want to account for bad binding **and** null values, it's up to you. Either way, you should use FallbackValue often.

Answer (score 0):

Create a checkboxContent property in viewmodel

set a default value to its private variable _checkboxContent  = "FooText";

Bind this property to checkbox Content

When the object loads, assign the object property to checkboxContent property